# Can assoc-in create a new vector instead of a new map?

Tags: clojure

assoc-in can change a value at an index/key in vectors/maps. In maps, if an key does not exist, then it makes a new key/value pair. Is there something similiar for vectors (if an index does not exist, it makes a list with that value at that index) Something like:

```
 (reduce (fn [g [x y]] (assoc-in g [x y] y ))
        []
        (for [x (range 2) 
              y (range 2)]
             [x y]))
```

above code generates:

```
[{1 1, 0 0} {1 1, 0 0}]
```

I want it to generate:

```
[[0 1] [0 1]]
```

Is this possible in a simple way?

Thanks

EDIT:
To be more clear, I Just want it to generate nested vectors instead of nested maps (or a vector of maps) Now I put y as a value but that's just an example.

Comment: Can you clarify what `[[0 1] [0 1]]` means? Is it a vector of two vectors created from `(range 2)`? or something else?

Comment: Sure, sorry to be unclear. I Just want it to generate nested vectors instead of nested maps (or vector of maps) I'll edit my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating a vector rather than a map won't work well in the general case because you can only `assoc` an existing index or the next index in a vector:

```
user=> (assoc [:a] 0 :b) ; works because index 0 exists
[:b]
user=> (assoc [:a] 1 :b) ; works because index 1 is next
[:a :b]
user=> (assoc [:a] 2 :b) ; fails since index is out of range
IndexOutOfBoundsException   clojure.lang.PersistentVector.assocN (PersistentVector.java:136)
```

However, if you're careful you can still make it work. Here is the implementation for `assoc-in`:

```
(defn assoc-in
  [m [k & ks] v]
  (if ks
    (assoc m k (assoc-in (get m k) ks v))
    (assoc m k v)))
```

Notice that it calls `get` on the true branch of the `if` condition. If you want your own version of `assoc-in` that uses vectors instead, you can add an empty vector as the default value returned by `get`:

```
(defn vassoc-in
  [m [k & ks] v]
  (if ks
    (assoc m k (vassoc-in (get m k []) ks v))
    (assoc m k v)))
```

Using `vassoc-in` rather than `assoc-in` in the sample code in your question results in `[[0 1] [0 1]]` just like you wanted.

Comment: @user1782011 - Glad to hear it! If this is what you were looking for then you can accept my answer to indicate that this question has been answered.

Comment: did it, better late then never :) sorry for the delay

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need something like:

```
user=> (let [cv #(apply vector %)] 
         (cv (map cv (repeat 5 (range 2)))))
[[0 1] [0 1] [0 1] [0 1] [0 1]]
```

Comment: `#(apply vector %)` is just `vec`.